# increase width of a text element by transition without wraping its content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a phone button on my website ringing.
It will expand by hover on it and show the phone numbers we have and it is working properly but we do not want to wrap text when expanding with transition. Do you guys have any idea how can i do this?

I have tried `overflow-x: hidden` but it is still wraping text into two line when expanding.

```js
document.getElementById("increase-width").addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        document.querySelector('#increase-width').style.width = "100%";     
        // document.querySelector('#increase-width span a').style.opacity = "1";    
        document.querySelector('#tel-parent').style.float = "left"; 
        document.querySelector('#tel-parent').style.width = "190px"; 
        document.querySelector('#tel').style.display = "block"; 
        // document.querySelector('#tel').style.transition = "opacity 2.5s";    
        document.querySelector('#increase-width').style.transition = "width 1s ease-in-out"; 
        document.querySelector('#tel-parent').style.transition = "width 1s ease-in-out"; 
});

document.getElementById("increase-width").addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    // document.querySelector('#increase-width span a').style.opacity = "0";    
    document.querySelector('#tel-parent').style.width = "55px"; 
    document.querySelector('#tel').style.display = "none"; 
    document.querySelector('#increase-width').style.transition = "width 1s ease-in-out"; 
    document.querySelector('#tel-parent').style.transition = "width 1s ease-in-out"; 
});
```

```css
.p-16 {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 47px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
.radius-50 {
  border-radius: 66px;
}
.bg-violet {
  background: #F8F7FA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="p-16" id="tel-parent" style="float: left; width: 55px; transition: width 1s ease-in-out 0s;">
            <div class="bg-violet radius-50 p-16" id="increase-width" style="width: 100%; transition: width 1s ease-in-out 0s;">
                <span class="text-orange show-on-hover" id="tel" style="display: none;">
                     <a id="021" href="tel:" style="color: #FF7200;">021-98780000</a> - 
                     <a id="1533" href="tel:" style="color: #FF7200;">6566</a>
                </span>

                <img src="/uploads/2022/10/fi-rr-phone-call-1.svg" id="img-on-hover" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And  does anyone know how can i clean code & write my scripts better.I think it is a little messy

Comment: If you're using JavaScript to set styles with hover events, then you're using the wrong tools for the job. CSS can do all these things better with [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo class. Are these supposed to be two separate phone numbers or a single one? Because you have 2 separate `<a>` tags with both a part of the number.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier thanks Emiel for your advice i will try that. they are two seperate phone numers

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found out i should add a simple css like below code to `#tel-parent`:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

And for a better appearance you can add to previous element

```
overflow-x:hidden
```